# Put content in shaped divs

Tags: css

I'm trying to make divs that are shaped like slices of a circle, using this code (this is for the top section of the circle) in CSS:

```
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 250px solid transparent;
border-right: 250px solid transparent;
border-top: 250px solid #FFA8A8;
border-bottom: 250px solid transparent;
position: fixed;
border-radius: 100%;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -250px;
margin-left: -250px;
```

and that makes the divs show up the way I want them to on the page, but when I try to put any text into them, it doesn't show up. I think I get why (because the actual height and width of the div are 0 and what shows up on the page is just the border), but how would I make divs that look the same but can contain text or images?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's difficult to reproduce this without it. It would help if you could update your question to list all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

instead border, use overflow to cut off round parts.

flex can also help with centering things

example:

```css
body>div {
  width: 80vmin;
  height: 80vmin;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  counter-reset: divs;
}

div div {
  background: #FFA8A8;
  height: 40vmin;
  width: 40vmin;
  counter-increment: divs;
  display: flex;
}

div div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: gray;
  order: 1
}

div div:last-child {
  order: 2
}

div div:before {
  content: counter(divs);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 10vmin
}

html {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  transform: rotate(-45deg)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

[pen](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bRKBgg)

Answer (score 0):

**Using the code you provided, and going off possibly incorrect assumptions**, I have come up with some code that will work for you. You can add text inside the div using absolute positioning and the top and left values to get your text where you would like it.

**Changes Made**:
Added flex to the body to center the slice. Took out width, height, position, top, left, and margin. Reduced the border radius to 50% since that is all that is needed to create the rounded edge. Reduced the border by 100px purely so that the example slice was not so big.

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.slice{
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  border-top: 150px solid #FFA8A8;
  border-bottom: 150px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

p{
  position: absolute;
  left:39%;;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slice">
  <p>Some Text That Fits</p>
</div>
```